# Cannot iterate over a Tensor with unknown first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to run this code in Kaggle.

However, the code in Kaggle calls a cognitive model for transfer learning and proceeds with learning, and I am going to proceed with learning with the model I created.

But this error pops up and I don't know why. I can't understand what you posted.

I specified the input shape, but why can't I find the dimension?

And I'm using Tensorflow. I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Thank you for reading.

```
def load_layers():
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, ColorChannels))

    #model.add(layers.Input(shape=input_tensor))
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(9,9), input_shape=input_tensor))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(6,6), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    baseModel = model(input_tensor=input_tensor)
    headModel = baseModel.output   
    headModel = Dense(10, activation="sigmoid")(headModel)
    model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
    
    for layer in baseModel.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    print("Compiling model...")
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                    optimizer='adam',
                    metrics=["accuracy"])

    return model

if TPU_INIT:
    with tpu_strategy.scope():
        model = load_layers()
else:
    model = load_layers()

model.summary()
```

**Output**

> Cannot iterate over a Tensor with unknown first dimension.

**Expected**
printed model.summary()

Comment: I define the model in this function

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not build correctly. The following code should fix your problem:

```
def load_layers():
    # input_tensor = Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, ColorChannels))
    INPUT_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, ColorChannels)  # <- HERE

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, filters=32, kernel_size=(9,9)))  # <- HERE
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(6,6), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))  # <- HERE
    
    # baseModel = model()
    # headModel = baseModel.output
    # headModel = Dense(10, activation="sigmoid")(headModel)
    # model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
    
    for layer in model.layers[:-1]:  # <- HERE
        layer.trainable = False

    print("Compiling model...")
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
                    optimizer='adam',
                    metrics=["accuracy"])

    return model
```

Output:

```
IMG_SIZE = 256
ColorChannels = 3

model = load_layers()
model.summary()

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 248, 248, 32)      7808      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 124, 124, 32)     0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 119, 119, 64)      73792     
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 119, 119, 64)      0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 59, 59, 64)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 55, 55, 128)       204928    
                                                                 
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 55, 55, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 27, 27, 128)      0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 25, 25, 128)       147584    
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling  (None, 12, 12, 128)      0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 18432)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1024)              18875392  
                                                                 
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 512)               524800    
                                                                 
 dropout_3 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 10)                5130      
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 10)                110       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 19,839,544
Trainable params: 110
Non-trainable params: 19,839,434
_________________________________________________________________
```